# How to parse child item in react native?

Tags: reactjs, json, native

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
<AntDesign name="flag" size={12} color="black" style={{ marginTop: 3, marginRight: 10 }} />
<Text style={styles.H1}>{item.name}</Text>
 <Text style={styles.H2}>{item.location}</Text>
 </View>
```

item is correctly parsing json name. But I've two items in location {flag:'', country:''}

How I could parse these two items in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to render the location then you can try this provided location is an object with flag and country as properties of location

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <AntDesign name="flag" size={12} color="black" style={{ marginTop: 
     3, marginRight: 10 }} />
     <Text style={styles.H1}>{item.name}</Text>
     <Text style={styles.H2}>{item.location.country} </Text>
     <Text style={styles.H2}>{item.location.flag} </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I've tried it and shows the following error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')
The json array is:
{
"name": "Judy Dixon",
 "location": {
            "country": "Yemen",
            "flag": ""
        }
}

Comment: if am correct the app displays **Judy Dixon**  if the location part is removed? if that is true then something is mutating the location object thats why we cant call **._country** on it or **.country** , it wasnt suppose to throw error, please check if you are displaying list of items maybe some of the items dont have a location object

Comment: It is location and by default its value is "Yemen". Name displaying correctly. If add country code it throws error.